How to remove freeze plugin delegate mpl core
I am using mpl core and I am trying to remove the freeze delegate plugin, but getting this error
  logs: [
    'Program 5TXoYuQbVzpFAqp2HdRtsAnH42pnps156V4WH8cHWGPz invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: CancelRentCore',
    'Program log: calling unlock core',
    'Program log: asset manager authority GRa8XGiSERUKN5jMRKMiMG9Xu3uCxgBN3EGGNzW4dyuC',
    'Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: RemovePlugin',
    'Program log: FreezeDelegate: Rejected',
    'Program log: Invalid Authority',
    'Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d consumed 10529 of 280011 compute units',
    'Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d failed: custom program error: 0x9',
    'Program 5TXoYuQbVzpFAqp2HdRtsAnH42pnps156V4WH8cHWGPz consumed 30518 of 300000 compute units',
    'Program 5TXoYuQbVzpFAqp2HdRtsAnH42pnps156V4WH8cHWGPz failed: custom program error: 0x9'
  ]
}

I think the error might be because the asset is frozen, and if so how do I unfreeze the asset?
Here is the Rust program code
  RemovePluginV1CpiBuilder::new(&self.core_program.clone().unwrap().as_ref())
            .asset(&self.asset_account)
            .payer(from)
            .authority(Some(&to))
            .plugin_type(PluginType::FreezeDelegate)
            .system_program(&self.system_program)
            .invoke_signed(asset_manager_signer)?;


Depending on what you are trying to achieve you would either thaw the Asset, or remove the plugin altogether.
Those are examples using the umi JS SDK @metaplex-foundation/mpl-core.
To remove a plugin completely you would have to use:
  const result = removePluginV1(umi, {
    asset: asset.publicKey,
    pluginType: PluginType.FreezeDelegate,
  }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

To just thaw the asset you would update the plugin using data frozen: false.
  await updatePluginV1(umi, {
    asset: asset.publicKey,
    plugin: createPlugin({ type: 'FreezeDelegate', data: { frozen: false } }),
  }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

